# Getting "Invalid Syntax" Error when creating variable

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm creating this program for an assignment. I'm trying to create a variable to name a new variable that'll be printed later in the code.

```
"""
This program asks the user for three ingredients,
three amounts, and a number of servings, and
determines how much of each ingredient is needed
to serve the specified number of servings.
"""

# Write program here...
print("Welcome to Salad Calculator!")
firstfood = input("What is the first ingredient?: ")
firstounce = float(input("How many ounces of this ingredient do you need?: ")
secounce = input("What is the second ingredient?: ")
secounce = float(input("How many ounces of this ingredient do you need?: ")
thirfood = input("What is the third ingredient?: ")
thirounce = float(input("How many ounces of this ingredient do you need?: ")
servings = int(input("How many servings do you need to make? (Enter a whole number): ")
print(" ")

print("You will need " + str(firstounce * servings) + " ounces of " + firstfood)
print("You will need " + str(secounce * servings) + " ounces of " + secfood)
print("You will need " + str(thirounce * servings) + " ounces of " + thirfood)
```

When ran I get:

```
File "main.py", line 12
    secounce = input("What is the second ingredient?: ")
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've seen other people having problems similar to mine, but I'm not sure what's wrong. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't closed all parentheses in your declaration of `firstounce` (you have `float(input(...)`).

Comment: You missed a `)` in the line before.

Comment: A small hint: Using an f-string will make your life easier when you output the data: `print(f'You will need {firstounce * servings} ounces of {firstfood}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firstounce` lacked the second closing parenthesis. the following is the fixed code

```
"""
This program asks the user for three ingredients,
three amounts, and a number of servings, and
determines how much of each ingredient is needed
to serve the specified number of servings.
"""

# Write program here...
print("Welcome to Salad Calculator!")
firstfood = input("What is the first ingredient?: ")
firstounce = float(input("How many ounces of this ingredient do you need?: "))
secfood = input("What is the second ingredient?: ")
secounce = float(input("How many ounces of this ingredient do you need?: "))
thirfood = input("What is the third ingredient?: ")
thirounce = float(input("How many ounces of this ingredient do you need?: "))
servings = int(input("How many servings do you need to make? (Enter a whole number): "))
print(" ")

print("You will need " + str(firstounce * servings) + " ounces of " + firstfood)
print("You will need " + str(secounce * servings) + " ounces of " + secfood)
print("You will need " + str(thirounce * servings) + " ounces of " + thirfood)
```